# Trying to understand slices of lists

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to understand slices of it. I take a slice `[0:1]` of it:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> id(l[0])
140079803522784
>>> id(l[0:1][0])
140079803522784
```

They are the same. But:

```
>>> l[0]=7
>>> l
[7, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[0:1][0]=13
>>> l
[7, 2, 3, 4]
```

So the slice's 0-element is the same as the list's 0-element, but when I change it in the slice, it is not changed in the list. Why not?

Comment: Slicing creates a shallow *copy*...

Comment: Because slicing makes a new list.

Comment: Now try the same thing with arbitrary objects (a custom class for example) instead of integers (which are immutable). Your mind will be blown.

Comment: @DeepSpace I did that. Same thing: >>>l=[[1,2],[1,3]]
>>> l[0:1][0]=[7]
>>> l
[[1, 2], [1, 3]]

Comment: In your first example, `l[0]` and `l[0:1][0]` are nothing more than elements of `l`, specifically they are the first element, i.e. the number `1`.  They have no association with the original list.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. `l[0:1]` is another list. It's first element equals the first element of `l`, but I did not modified that element. I replaced it, so I changed the `l[0:1]` list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a new (shallow) copy of the list.

So basically when you do `l[0:1][0] = 13` you're assigning 13 as the value in a new list, not `l`.  It's the same as if you did

```
[l[0]] = 13
```

or

```
g = [l[0]]
g[0] = 13
```

Note this is only true for immutable types, such as `int` and `str`.  Since a slice performs a shallow copy, you'd get the behavior you'd expect if you modify an object.

```
>>> l = [{'hi': 7}, {}, {}, {}]
[{'hi': 7}, {}, {}, {}]
>>> l[0:1][0]['hi'] = 1
>>> l[0]
{'hi': 1}
```

Comment: It is a copy, yes, but the elements in the copy refer to the same elements as the original list. Also if I do `l[0:1]=[13]`, `l` is changed.

Comment: @ericj they do, but integers are immutable. And your second example is explicit slice assignment, of course `l` gets changed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I tried with mutable lists: `l=[[1,2],[1,3]];l[0:1][0]=[7]`. Then `l` is `[[1, 2], [1, 3]]`.

Comment: That example is **not** slice assignment. It's assigning by index into the *result* of a slice, effectively `m = l[0:1]; m[0] = [7]`. It's only slice assignment when the *last* index is a slice.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. `l[0:1]` is another list. It's first element equals the first element of `l`, but I did not modified that element. I replaced it, so I changed the `l[0:1]` list. Thanks.